# SharePoint online default templates

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, modern-experience, pnp-powershell, sitepages

I created 50 pages using the SharePoint online template called Blank.  This has a header / title webpart at the top which we do not want.

Does anyone know of a way to remove this webpart from all the pages or to how create a template without that webpart?

Also, if creating a template is possible, how could I apply this to all my pages quickly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PnP PowerShell script to remove page title / header section from SharePoint online modern experience site page:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName -Interactive
Set-PnPPage -Identity "MyPage" -LayoutType "Home" -Title "My Page"
```

Where `"MyPage"` is the name of your site page.

Also, you can follow the steps given in this article to create a new page without title/header section: [SharePoint Online: Create a blank page without header & title](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/03/26/sharepoint-online-create-a-blank-page-without-header-and-title/)

**References**:

1. [Installing PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/installation.html)